# create a friendly setup for my c# app using install shield app

Tags: c#, installshield

i am using VS2015 and i am using Install Shield Lite to create a setup.

I use the option of creating a 'singleimage'

the file produced is setup.exe.

The only trouble with this is that is this file is downloaded from my server via a browser window and as such invokes' several warning messages to the user (targeting Window 10 OS) which could put off a potential customer from trying my demo.

Am I right in thinking a MSI file would not trigger these warnings and if so is it possible to create using InstallShield please?

Thanks

Comment: hi, well general warnings like warning the user against downloading an 'exe' file

Comment: Did you sign the installer with a valid authenticode signature?

Comment: @ScottChamberlain Hi no. Never done this before. Looking at it  all now. Looks interesting. thanks

Comment: Which ones? Most of those apply to MSIs as well.  MSIs are not magically "more secure" than EXEs.

Comment: @SLaks point taken.  Never really had to concern myself with installers before like this.  A previous commentator suggested looking at the signing process. thanks

Comment: @ScottChamberlain thanks that did the trick. And thanks Slaks for your nudges :)

Comment: I made my comment in to a more complete answer

Comment: Try inno setup instead, i find it better. http://www.jrsoftware.org/isinfo.php

Comment: @AndersK. I shall take a look - thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the installer is not signed by a authenticode signature you will often run in to problems like this. Get a code signing certificate and sign the installer and it may solve your issues.